# Baffling python mysql connection issue

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Hello guys I am currently working in a python project at my school. First I want to make clear that I'm not a python programmer (I was just called to put out the flames in this project because no one else would and I was brave enough to say yes).

I have the following problem here. I have to write a method that connects to an existing localhost MySQL database (I'm using connector version 1.0.12 and python 2.6) and then does pretty basic stuff. The parameters are sent by a GTK-written GUI (I didn't write that interface). So I wrote my method like this:

```
def compMySQL(self, user, database, password, db_level, table_level, column_level):
    sql_page_textview = self.mainTree.get_widget('sql_text_view')
    sql_page_textview.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("courier 10"))
    sql_page_buffer = sql_page_textview.get_buffer()

    #Gonna try connecting to DB
    try:
        print("Calling conn with U:{0} P:{1} DB:{2}".format(user,password,database))
        cnxOMC = mysql.connector.connect(user, password,'localhost',database)
    except:
        print "Error: Database connection failed. User name or Database name may be wrong"
        return

    #More code ...
```

But when I run my code I get this:

```
Calling conn with U:root P:PK17LP12r DB:TESTERS
Error: Database connection failed. User name or Database name may be wrong
```

And I don't know why, since the arguments sent are the same arguments that get printed (telling me that the GUI the other guy coded works fine) and they are valid login parameters. If I hardcode the login parameters directly insetad of using the GUI everything goes ok and the functions executes properly; the following code executes nice and smooth:

```
def compMySQL(self, user, database, password, db_level, table_level, column_level):
    sql_page_textview = self.mainTree.get_widget('sql_text_view')
    sql_page_textview.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("courier 10"))
    sql_page_buffer = sql_page_textview.get_buffer()

    #Gonna try hardcoding
    try:
        #print("Calling conn with U:{0} P:{1} DB:{2}".format(user,password,database))
        cnxOMC = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password='PK17LP12r', host='localhost', database='TESTERS')
        print 'No prob with conn'
    except:
        print "Error: Database connection failed. User name or Database name may be wrong"
        return

    #more code ...
```

Console output:

```
No prob with conn
```

Any ideas guys? This one is killing me.  I'm just learning Python but I imagine the problem to be something very easy for a seasoned python developer so any help would be strongly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix your indentation first..

Comment: In your first code block, you have the order of the function's parameters as `user, database, password`. However, the usage order seems to be `user,password,database`. Are you sure that when you're calling the function, you're doing `('root', 'TESTERS', 'PK17LP12r', , ....)`?

Comment: Also, recommend not posting your actual password on a public website in the future (if that's indeed what it is).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two versions is not that you are hard coding the parameters in the second one, it is that you are calling by keyword args rather than positional ones. The docs for MySQL connector don't seem to give the actual positional order, and there's no reason to think they are in the order you've given, so looks like you should always call by kwarg:

```
cnxOMC = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password,host=host,database=database)
```